Why do we ground receptacles to their metal boxes?
I believe you need to ground receptacle boxes. What benefit is offered in doing so vs. running bare ground wire from the romex straight to the receptacle?

If the hot wire accidentally comes in contact with the metal box, having a grounded metal box will close the circuit and trip the breaker, telling you that something is wrong and to check the wires. If the metal box is not grounded and accidentally becomes hot, you touch it and get electrocuted.

Or start a fire since the breaker does not trip.

Also remember if you ground the receptacle, it will ground the box when the screws are used to attach the receptacle to the box.  The issue comes what the receptacle or switch is removed. Then the ground is removed as well. So it is better to ground the box, then everything mounted to the box is grounded as well.

Code requires that the metal box itself remain grounded, even if the receptacle or other device is removed.   NEC 250.148.
Given that all switches (and better receptacles) are "self-grounding" when installed in a metal box, there is no need to run a ground WIRE to the device at all.  NEC 404.9(B)(1) and 250.146(B). Thus, running ground to the metal box creates a neater installation, with all grounds shoved into the very back of the box at initial install time, and never handled again.  One fewer wire in all respects.
